# RegEx line shows warning in jsHint

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

I haave the following line in my code :

```
invitationMessage = invitationMessage.replace(/{{from}}/g, from);
```

when i do jsLint on the code, it shows the following warning

```
unescaped {
```

what is the correct way to write this statement? What is wrong with this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the value `{` and `}`:

```
invitationMessage = invitationMessage.replace(/\{\{from\}\}/g, from);
```

Because these are [`RegExp` symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range) which can be used like:

```
\*{1, 3}
```

It matches `*` or `**` or `***`. An asterisk with a length between `1` and `3`